# How to make dynamic array from static array

Tags: php, arrays

I have trouble with my static array, i need to update with dynamic array can someone help me ? because will be so hard if i have alot data and i must create 1 by 1.

$kriteria = [C1,C2,C3,C4,C5,C6];

$alternatif = [ALT1,ALT2,ALT,ALT4,ALT5,ALT6,ALT7];

```
$nEntropy = array();
    for ($i=0;$i<count($kriteria);$i++)
        {
            for ($j=0;$j<count($alternatif);$j++)
                {
                    $nEntropy[$i] = (((-1)/log(7)) *( 
                    ($probabilitas[0][0]*log($probabilitas[0][0]))+
                    ($probabilitas[1][0]*log($probabilitas[1][0]))+
                    ($probabilitas[2][0]*log($probabilitas[2][0]))+
                    ($probabilitas[3][0]*log($probabilitas[3][0]))+
                    ($probabilitas[4][0]*log($probabilitas[4][0]))+
                    ($probabilitas[5][0]*log($probabilitas[5][0]))+
                    ($probabilitas[6][0]*log($probabilitas[6][0]))
                ));
            }
        }

$nEntropy1 = array();
    for ($i=0;$i<count($kriteria);$i++)
        {
            for ($j=0;$j<count($alternatif);$j++)
                {
                    $nEntropy1[$i] = (((-1)/log(7)) *( 
                    ($probabilitas[0][1]*log($probabilitas[0][1]))+
                    ($probabilitas[1][1]*log($probabilitas[1][1]))+
                    ($probabilitas[2][1]*log($probabilitas[2][1]))+
                    ($probabilitas[3][1]*log($probabilitas[3][1]))+
                    ($probabilitas[4][1]*log($probabilitas[4][1]))+
                    ($probabilitas[5][1]*log($probabilitas[5][1]))+
                    ($probabilitas[6][1]*log($probabilitas[6][1]))
                ));
            }
        }

$nEntropy2 = array();
    for ($i=0;$i<count($kriteria);$i++)
        {
            for ($j=0;$j<count($alternatif);$j++)
                {
                    $nEntropy2[$i] = (((-1)/log(7)) *( 
                    ($probabilitas[0][2]*log($probabilitas[0][2]))+
                    ($probabilitas[1][2]*log($probabilitas[1][2]))+
                    ($probabilitas[2][2]*log($probabilitas[2][2]))+
                    ($probabilitas[3][2]*log($probabilitas[3][2]))+
                    ($probabilitas[4][2]*log($probabilitas[4][2]))+
                    ($probabilitas[5][2]*log($probabilitas[5][2]))+
                    ($probabilitas[6][2]*log($probabilitas[6][2]))
                ));
            }
        }

$nEntropy3 = array();
    for ($i=0;$i<count($kriteria);$i++)
        {
            for ($j=0;$j<count($alternatif);$j++)
                {
                    $nEntropy3[$i] = (((-1)/log(7)) *( 
                    ($probabilitas[0][3]*log($probabilitas[0][3]))+
                    ($probabilitas[1][3]*log($probabilitas[1][3]))+
                    ($probabilitas[2][3]*log($probabilitas[2][3]))+
                    ($probabilitas[3][3]*log($probabilitas[3][3]))+
                    ($probabilitas[4][3]*log($probabilitas[4][3]))+
                    ($probabilitas[5][3]*log($probabilitas[5][3]))+
                    ($probabilitas[6][3]*log($probabilitas[6][3]))
                ));
            }
        }

$nEntropyy4 = array();
    for ($i=0;$i<count($kriteria);$i++)
        {
            for ($j=0;$j<count($alternatif);$j++)
                {
                    $nEntropy4[$i] = (((-1)/log(7)) *( 
                    ($probabilitas[0][4]*log($probabilitas[0][4]))+
                    ($probabilitas[1][4]*log($probabilitas[1][4]))+
                    ($probabilitas[2][4]*log($probabilitas[2][4]))+
                    ($probabilitas[3][4]*log($probabilitas[3][4]))+
                    ($probabilitas[4][4]*log($probabilitas[4][4]))+
                    ($probabilitas[5][4]*log($probabilitas[5][4]))+
                    ($probabilitas[6][4]*log($probabilitas[6][4]))
                ));
            }
        }

$nEntropy5 = array();
    for ($i=0;$i<count($kriteria);$i++)
        {
            for ($j=0;$j<count($alternatif);$j++)
                {
                    $nEntropy5[$i] = (((-1)/log(7)) *( 
                    ($probabilitas[0][5]*log($probabilitas[0][5]))+
                    ($probabilitas[1][5]*log($probabilitas[1][5]))+
                    ($probabilitas[2][5]*log($probabilitas[2][5]))+
                    ($probabilitas[3][5]*log($probabilitas[3][5]))+
                    ($probabilitas[4][5]*log($probabilitas[4][5]))+
                    ($probabilitas[5][5]*log($probabilitas[5][5]))+
                    ($probabilitas[6][5]*log($probabilitas[6][5]))
                ));
            }
        }

showb($nEntropy);
showb($nEntropy1);
showb($nEntropy2);
showb($nEntropy3);
showb($nEntropy4);
showb($nEntropy5);
```

this image for my results 
[image]
as you can see my code really static and so hard if i have alot data
and also i need my results likes this
[image]

**EDIT**
the answers from Vörös Amadea are correct, but there are still some that are lacking, my second question regarding the results is still in large numbers. is there a way to display it only once?
as u can see on my image before, i need to remove duplicate data so only 1 for each is who will displayed and store it into array.
[image]

I have modified a little code from Vörös Amadea because if I don't modify it, I get an error "Undefined variable: probability"

this is the code that I have modified.

```
for($x=0;$x<1;$x++){
$nth = $x;
$entz = array();
for ($i=0;$i<count($kriteria);$i++)
    {
        for ($j=0;$j<count($alternatif);$j++)
            {
                ${"entz$nth"}[$i] = (((-1)/log(7)) *( 
                ($probabilitas[0][$nth]*log($probabilitas[0][$nth]))+
                ($probabilitas[1][$nth]*log($probabilitas[1][$nth]))+
                ($probabilitas[2][$nth]*log($probabilitas[2][$nth]))+
                ($probabilitas[3][$nth]*log($probabilitas[3][$nth]))+
                ($probabilitas[4][$nth]*log($probabilitas[4][$nth]))+
                ($probabilitas[5][$nth]*log($probabilitas[5][$nth]))+
                ($probabilitas[6][$nth]*log($probabilitas[6][$nth]))
                ));
            }
        }
    }
showb(${"entz$nth"});
```

Comment: You/re going to have to clarify your question a bit more. All arrays are dynamic, meaning they can be manipulated. You understand your data, but it's not really clear what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: my code is so broken, i need to create entropy1,2,3.... for define that, i mean can i just use single entropy? and also i create static likes $probabilitas[0][5], i need dynamic maybe like $probabilitas[$i][$j].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate variable names in for loops like this.
Just change the value of `$how_many_i_want`.

```
$how_many_i_want = 3;

for($x=0;$x<$how_many_i_want;$x++){
    generate_entropy($x);
}

function generate_entropy($nth){
    $kriteria = ['C1','C2','C3','C4','C5','C6'];
    $alternatif = ['ALT1','ALT2','ALT','ALT4','ALT5','ALT6','ALT7'];

    ${"nEntropy$nth"} = array();
    for ($i=0;$i<count($kriteria);$i++){
        for ($j=0;$j<count($alternatif);$j++){
            ${"nEntropy$nth"}[$i] = (((-1)/log(7)) *(
                    ($probabilitas[0][$nth]*log($probabilitas[0][$nth]))+
                    ($probabilitas[1][$nth]*log($probabilitas[1][$nth]))+
                    ($probabilitas[2][$nth]*log($probabilitas[2][$nth]))+
                    ($probabilitas[3][$nth]*log($probabilitas[3][$nth]))+
                    ($probabilitas[4][$nth]*log($probabilitas[4][$nth]))+
                    ($probabilitas[5][$nth]*log($probabilitas[5][$nth]))+
                    ($probabilitas[6][$nth]*log($probabilitas[6][$nth]))
                ));
        }
    }
    showb(${"nEntropy$nth"});
}
```

Comment: have error message  Undefined variable: probabilitas

Comment: I have modified your code, and the results went well but only for the first question. for the second question it's still not running. can you help me?

Comment: @AdventureMarvelous, you really should not add questions after answers have been given. At the time this answer was given there was one question. Moreover there should not be more than one question any way. Ask a new question via the appropriate button if you have a new question. You can refer in it to this question. If indeed the "results went well ... for the first question", you should mark this answer as accepted.

Comment: no, from the beginning my question was two. 1. i need to update with dynamic array 2. "as you can see my code really static and so hard if i have a lot data and also i need my results likes this " and i already give Black Box on image, is mean if i just need 1 row for the results. maybe you need to check my edit question. No problem, if you just want to get mark i'll give you and i will open new question

Comment: I have opened a new question, maybe you can help answer it?

Comment: *"If you just want to get mark i'll give you..."*: Did you maybe think I was the author of this answer?