# Remove redudant data array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

From my question before [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54054583/how-to-make-dynamic-array-from-static-array) there are still unfinished problems.
Array results is redudant. I just need single data foreach 
atm results like this 
[image]

and i just want to be like this
[image]

i need to remove duplicate data so only 1 for each is who will displayed and store it into array. 
so i can use the array and when i call, array will give me like

```
   array(
0.94197664983117,
0.94197664983117,
0.96085998187867,
0.96055551656181,
0.94850004357715,
0.95310290634961,
0.95625985627734
);
```

i use this code

```
for($x=0;$x<1;$x++){
$nth = $x;
$entz = array();
for ($i=0;$i<count($kriteria);$i++)
    {
        for ($j=0;$j<count($alternatif);$j++)
            {
                ${"entz$nth"}[$i] = (((-1)/log(7)) *( 
                ($probabilitas[0][$nth]*log($probabilitas[0][$nth]))+
                ($probabilitas[1][$nth]*log($probabilitas[1][$nth]))+
                ($probabilitas[2][$nth]*log($probabilitas[2][$nth]))+
                ($probabilitas[3][$nth]*log($probabilitas[3][$nth]))+
                ($probabilitas[4][$nth]*log($probabilitas[4][$nth]))+
                ($probabilitas[5][$nth]*log($probabilitas[5][$nth]))+
                ($probabilitas[6][$nth]*log($probabilitas[6][$nth]))
                ));
            }
        }
    }
showb(${"entz$nth"});
```

**EDIT**

first this is my $probabilitas data 
[image]

and i just want to get the results for each kriteria like this
[image]

how to get the results? im using formula like this

> c1 = (-1/log(7)) *
>   ((0,217391304*log(0,217391304))+(0,086956522*log(0,086956522))+(0,043478261*log(0,043478261))+(0,086956522*log(0,086956522))+(0,217391304*log(0,217391304))+(0,173913043*log(0,173913043))+(0,173913043*log(0,173913043)))
>
> c2= (-1/log(7)) *
>   ((0,043478261*log(0,043478261))+(0,173913043*log(0,173913043))+(0,173913043*log(0,173913043))+(0,173913043*log(0,173913043))+(0,173913043*log(0,173913043))+(0,173913043*log(0,173913043))+(0,086956522*log(0,086956522)))
>
> c3= (-1/log(7)) *
>   ((0,238095238*log(0,238095238))+(0,095238095*log(0,095238095))+(0,095238095*log(0,095238095))+(0,19047619*log(0,19047619))+(0,19047619*log(0,19047619))+(0,095238095*log(0,095238095))+(0,095238095*log(0,095238095)))
>
> c4= (-1/log(7)) *
>   ((0,071428571*log(0,071428571))+(0,178571429*log(0,178571429))+(0,178571429*log(0,178571429))+(0,178571429*log(0,178571429))+(0,035714286*log(0,035714286))+(0,178571429*log(0,178571429))+(0,178571429*log(0,178571429)))
>
> c5= (-1/log(7)) *
>   ((0,058823529*log(0,058823529))+(0,235294118*log(0,235294118))+(0,117647059*log(0,117647059))+(0,235294118*log(0,235294118))+(0,117647059*log(0,117647059))+(0,117647059*log(0,117647059))+(0,117647059*log(0,117647059)))
>
> c6= (-1/log(7)) *
>   ((0,208333333*log(0,208333333))+(0,166666667*log(0,166666667))+(0,166666667*log(0,166666667))+(0,083333333*log(0,083333333))+(0,166666667*log(0,166666667))+(0,166666667*log(0,166666667))+(0,041666667*log(0,041666667)))

for static code i can use this code

```
$nEntropy = array();
    for ($i=0;$i<count($kriteria);$i++)
        {
            for ($j=0;$j<count($alternatif);$j++)
                {
                    $nEntropy[$i] = (((-1)/log(7)) *( 
                    ($probabilitas[0][0]*log($probabilitas[0][0]))+
                    ($probabilitas[1][0]*log($probabilitas[1][0]))+
                    ($probabilitas[2][0]*log($probabilitas[2][0]))+
                    ($probabilitas[3][0]*log($probabilitas[3][0]))+
                    ($probabilitas[4][0]*log($probabilitas[4][0]))+
                    ($probabilitas[5][0]*log($probabilitas[5][0]))+
                    ($probabilitas[6][0]*log($probabilitas[6][0]))
                ));
            }
        }

    $nEntropy1 = array();
        for ($i=0;$i<count($kriteria);$i++)
            {
                for ($j=0;$j<count($alternatif);$j++)
                    {
                        $nEntropy1[$i] = (((-1)/log(7)) *( 
                        ($probabilitas[0][1]*log($probabilitas[0][1]))+
                        ($probabilitas[1][1]*log($probabilitas[1][1]))+
                        ($probabilitas[2][1]*log($probabilitas[2][1]))+
                        ($probabilitas[3][1]*log($probabilitas[3][1]))+
                        ($probabilitas[4][1]*log($probabilitas[4][1]))+
                        ($probabilitas[5][1]*log($probabilitas[5][1]))+
                        ($probabilitas[6][1]*log($probabilitas[6][1]))
                    ));
                }
            }

    $nEntropy2 = array();
        for ($i=0;$i<count($kriteria);$i++)
            {
                for ($j=0;$j<count($alternatif);$j++)
                    {
                        $nEntropy2[$i] = (((-1)/log(7)) *( 
                        ($probabilitas[0][2]*log($probabilitas[0][2]))+
                        ($probabilitas[1][2]*log($probabilitas[1][2]))+
                        ($probabilitas[2][2]*log($probabilitas[2][2]))+
                        ($probabilitas[3][2]*log($probabilitas[3][2]))+
                        ($probabilitas[4][2]*log($probabilitas[4][2]))+
                        ($probabilitas[5][2]*log($probabilitas[5][2]))+
                        ($probabilitas[6][2]*log($probabilitas[6][2]))
                    ));
                }
            }

    $nEntropy3 = array();
        for ($i=0;$i<count($kriteria);$i++)
            {
                for ($j=0;$j<count($alternatif);$j++)
                    {
                        $nEntropy3[$i] = (((-1)/log(7)) *( 
                        ($probabilitas[0][3]*log($probabilitas[0][3]))+
                        ($probabilitas[1][3]*log($probabilitas[1][3]))+
                        ($probabilitas[2][3]*log($probabilitas[2][3]))+
                        ($probabilitas[3][3]*log($probabilitas[3][3]))+
                        ($probabilitas[4][3]*log($probabilitas[4][3]))+
                        ($probabilitas[5][3]*log($probabilitas[5][3]))+
                        ($probabilitas[6][3]*log($probabilitas[6][3]))
                    ));
                }
            }

    $nEntropyy4 = array();
        for ($i=0;$i<count($kriteria);$i++)
            {
                for ($j=0;$j<count($alternatif);$j++)
                    {
                        $nEntropy4[$i] = (((-1)/log(7)) *( 
                        ($probabilitas[0][4]*log($probabilitas[0][4]))+
                        ($probabilitas[1][4]*log($probabilitas[1][4]))+
                        ($probabilitas[2][4]*log($probabilitas[2][4]))+
                        ($probabilitas[3][4]*log($probabilitas[3][4]))+
                        ($probabilitas[4][4]*log($probabilitas[4][4]))+
                        ($probabilitas[5][4]*log($probabilitas[5][4]))+
                        ($probabilitas[6][4]*log($probabilitas[6][4]))
                    ));
                }
            }

    $nEntropy5 = array();
        for ($i=0;$i<count($kriteria);$i++)
            {
                for ($j=0;$j<count($alternatif);$j++)
                    {
                        $nEntropy5[$i] = (((-1)/log(7)) *( 
                        ($probabilitas[0][5]*log($probabilitas[0][5]))+
                        ($probabilitas[1][5]*log($probabilitas[1][5]))+
                        ($probabilitas[2][5]*log($probabilitas[2][5]))+
                        ($probabilitas[3][5]*log($probabilitas[3][5]))+
                        ($probabilitas[4][5]*log($probabilitas[4][5]))+
                        ($probabilitas[5][5]*log($probabilitas[5][5]))+
                        ($probabilitas[6][5]*log($probabilitas[6][5]))
                    ));
                }
            }

    showb($nEntropy);
    showb($nEntropy1);
    showb($nEntropy2);
    showb($nEntropy3);
    showb($nEntropy4);
    showb($nEntropy5);
```

if I use the code, then I have to use it repeatedly. this will be very troublesome if the number of $ criteria and $ alternative is unknown. Therefore I want to make it dynamically. So I don't need to rewrite the code at any time. The results of my code also become redundant. I only want to display one time

[image]

Comment: [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) ? unclear what you are asking. Where do other columns come from?

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone I have given a link from the previous question.

Comment: [ask] especially [mcve] emphasis on *complete*

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone I have added some information, please see my latest update.

Comment: It is not obvious where the array `$probabilitas` comes from. Almost nobody wants to guess and hand-code any probable array structure based on a table image. [var_export](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php)

Comment: Probably the complete approach is done wrong, generating data never needed and now you try to remove it afterwards. You are likely running into an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take this code, is this what you're trying to do?

```
$probabilitas =
array (
    array (
        0.21739130434783,
        0.043478260869565,
        0.23809523809524,
        0.071428571428571,
        0.058823529411765,
        0.20833333333333
    ),

    array (
        0.08695652173913,
        0.17391304347826,
        0.095238095238095,
        0.17857142857143,
        0.23529411764706,
        0.16666666666667
    ),

    array (
        0.043478260869565,
        0.17391304347826,
        0.095238095238095,
        0.17857142857143,
        0.11764705882353,
        0.16666666666667
    ),

    array (
        0.08695652173913,
        0.17391304347826,
        0.19047619047619,
        0.17857142857143,
        0.23529411764706,
        0.083333333333333
    ),

    array (
        0.21739130434783,
        0.17391304347826,
        0.19047619047619,
        0.035714285714286,
        0.11764705882353,
        0.16666666666667
    ),

    array (
        0.17391304347826,
        0.17391304347826,
        0.095238095238095,
        0.17857142857143,
        0.11764705882353,
        0.16666666666667
    ),

    array (
        0.17391304347826,
        0.08695652173913,
        0.095238095238095,
        0.17857142857143,
        0.11764705882353,
        0.041666666666667
    )
);

// UPDATE
// 7 alternatif arrays, each with 6 element
$alternatif_count = count($probabilitas[0]);

// We choose eg. every first element of every alternatif array, and push them onto a column array
for($j=0; $j<$alternatif_count; $j++){
    $col_arr[] = array_column($probabilitas, $j);
}

// Then for each column we calculate entropy
$entropy_arr = array();
foreach($col_arr as $col){
    $calc = 0;
    foreach($col as $prob){
        $calc += $prob * log($prob);
        $entropy = ((-1)/log(7)) * $calc;
    }
    array_push($entropy_arr, $entropy);
}

//showb($entropy_arr);
```

**UPDATE**
Please test this, and verify if the calculation method is correct.

Comment: I have added some information, please see my latest update.

Comment: wow, you are so cool. thank you very much, this is what i expected. but why when I use Showb ($entropy) an error message appears? like this : Message: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Comment: maybe you need to store it into array @AdventureMarvelous

Comment: @AdityaDS I have tried it but there is notice of undefined offset 0 when I tried to take the key value.

Comment: :D It was interesting to solve.
Hm may be because $entropy is not an array, and looks like your showb function needs one. Let's try pushing the entropy values into an arr and showb that

Comment: very good, now my problem is finished thanks to your help. You are very kind, thank you very much man. @VörösAmadea

Answer (score 0):

based on an answer from @VörösAmadea, I just tried adding a little, maybe it will work. But I haven't tried the code yet.

```
$alternatif_count = count($probabilitas[0]);
          for($j=0; $j<$alternatif_count; $j++){
          $col_arr[] = array_column($probabilitas, $j);
       }
    $entropys = array();
    $no=-1;
    foreach($col_arr as $col){
       $no++;
       $calc = 0;
          foreach($col as $prob){
              $calc += $prob * log($prob);
              $entropy = ((-1)/log(7)) * $calc;
          }
       $entropys[$no] = $entropy;
    }

    showb($entropys);
```